# Locate but exclude names - Linux

Tags: linux, locate

I am trying to locate all the files named `hosts` on a linux PC remotely.  The problem is there are almost several thousand files with `ghostscript` as one of the upper directory names or as part of a directory name, so it's returning ALL of those directories.  Is there a way to locate `hosts`, but exclude `ghosts`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pipe the output into a grep -v command to exclude ghostscript

```
| grep -v "ghostscript"
```

Comment: This is the one that worked best for me.  It excluded "ghostscript", but also found files with hosts in the name, such as "known_hosts", et al.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

When you do `locate hosts` it is as if you did `locate '*hosts*'` (where `*` can also match `/`) which is why you match a lot more. You need to provide at least one glob character explicitly to override this, so use

```
locate '*/hosts'
```

If you want any file with `hosts` at the end, use `*hosts`. If you want any file with hosts in the middle it depends on your version of locate. As *steeldriver* noted, mlocate takes `-b` to apply the pattern to just the basename, so you can do

```
locate -b '*hosts*'
```

and with GNU locate you can use a regexp

```
locate -r '[^/]*hosts[^/]*$'
```

Comment: Thank you - that gave me most results, but excluded a couple others I might need, such as "known_hosts", "phxhosts" et al.

Comment: Just remove the explicit `/`, i.e.  `'*hosts'`.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
find /path/to/directory/ -type f -name "hosts" -not -path "*ghostscript*"
```